# A little hard double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

$\iint \frac{2x^2e^{x^2}}{x^2+y^2}dxdy\::\:D=\left\{1\le x\le 2,\:0\le y\le x\right\}$

I use the substitution: $u=x^2,\:v=\frac{y}{x}$
$$$$Then I get: $\iint\frac{ue^u}{u+v^2u^2}dudv\::\:D\tilde{=}\left\{1\le u\le 4,\:0\le v\le 1\right\}$

Now by integration by parts, first of all by $dv$ I get: $$\int _1^4\:\frac{e^u}{\sqrt{u}}\arctan \left(\sqrt{u}\right)du$$

I can eather take the integral first of all by u using integration by parts and then to get a similiar expression with multiply of arctg(with both variables in the argument) and some expression that includes one of the variable.

But maybe the second way gives me the solution after technical calculations, because In the first way, I dont see how can i calculate the integral at all? 
Am I right or anybody see's something good from what I got?

P.S - I get wrong in what I wrote about the second way, it is integral of a kind:

$$\frac{e^u}{u}du$$ so I dont see a way to avoid what I got, so maybe I had done a calculation mistake or I dont know how to calculate that integral.

Comment: Did you try polar coordinates?

Comment: There is a clue int the exercise that say's it can be solved also by polar coordinates, but it says also about that substitution, and I did'nt want to use polar because I thought it would be easier. So look's like it isn't, right ?

Comment: No, I was asking because the integrand looked good with polar substitutions. After looking at the domain, I changed my mind.

Comment: @Ilya.K. Using your substitution, I think the integral should be  ${\iint\frac{ue^u}{u+v^2\color{red}{u}}dudv=\iint\frac{e^u}{1+v^2}dudv}$. This should simplify more nicely.

Comment: You know what? It does work fine with polar coordinates (realized this after some scratching on the paper). The limits of $\theta$ are $0$ and $\pi/4$, and those of $r$ are $\frac1{\cos(\theta)}$ and $\frac2{\cos(\theta)}$. The integral is straightforward to compute, I think you should get: $\frac{\pi}4 (e^4 - e)$.

Comment: @BolzWeir Your result is correct, as I obtain the same $$\int_1^4e^u\int_0^1\frac{1}{1+v^2}\ dv du=\int_1^4e^u[\arctan(v)]^1_0 du=\frac{\pi}{4}(e^4-e)$$

Comment: And yes, Ahmed, you right about the calculation mistake. Thank you )

Comment: @Ilya.K. Your welcome.